# sorting vector by time

Tags: c++, boost

Previously had to sort a vector in order of time... most recent first.

I succeeded in this however was abit surprised by the way this had to be done.

In my predicate function I do the following. (is a predicate within `std::sort`)

```
if(t.GetTime() != p.GetTime())
{
    return t.GetTime() > p.GetTime()
}
```

This sorts the elements correctly (most recent first)... I thought that the less than operator would do this however the less than operator has the oldest element first. But not sure why?

i.e 2.00 pm is less than 3.00pm but this would return false.

Please note GetTime() interally will call `is_less()` from boost.

Comment: post a minimal complete example that readers can try out

Comment: Most recent first means you want to sort from highest to lowest, so it makes sense that you need to reverse the sort.

Comment: also, the if doesn't make much sense. What do you do outside of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this. What I had before was actually correct for my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The sort algorithm is specified to order in ascending order. By default it uses `std::less<T>` to achieve this.

Of course, if you use `std::greater<T>` instead, you'll get the inverse effect, which is what you want.

Note that you might be happy with just default sort and reverse iterators (`rbegin()`,`rend()`):

```
std::sort(v.begin(), e.end()); // ascending by default comparison

// print in reverse order:
for(auto it = v.rbegin(); it!=v.rend(); ++it)
    std::cout << *it << " ";
```

If it's the tedium of spelling out the comparison just to order by a member, consider writing a small helper:

```
namespace detail {
    template <typename F> struct GreaterBy {
        GreaterBy(F&& f) : _f(std::move(f)) {}

        template <typename A, typename B>
            bool operator()(A const& a, B const& b) const {
                return std::greater<decltype(_f(a))>()(_f(a), _f(b));
            }
      private:
        F _f;
    };
}

template <typename F>
detail::GreaterBy<F> order_by_desc(F&& f) {
    return std::forward<F>(f);
}
```

Now you can simply:

```
std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), order_by_desc(std::mem_fn(&MyType::GetTime)));
```

### Live Demo

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8c49e56bc9cab807)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

#include <iostream>

namespace pt = boost::posix_time;

class MyType {
    using Clock = pt::second_clock;
    pt::ptime _ts;

  public:
    MyType(int seconds) : _ts(Clock::local_time() + pt::seconds(seconds)) {}

    pt::ptime GetTime() const { return _ts; }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyType const&v) {
        return os << "[" << v._ts << "]";
    }
};

namespace detail {
    template <typename F> struct GreaterBy {
        GreaterBy(F&& f) : _f(std::move(f)) {}

        template <typename A, typename B>
            bool operator()(A const& a, B const& b) const {
                return std::greater<decltype(_f(a))>()(_f(a), _f(b));
            }
      private:
        F _f;
    };
}

template <typename F>
detail::GreaterBy<F> order_by_desc(F&& f) {
    return std::forward<F>(f);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<MyType> values { 1, -3, 77, 130, 12, -99 };

    std::cout << "Before sort: ";
    for (auto& v : values)
        std::cout << v << " ";

    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end(), order_by_desc(std::mem_fn(&MyType::GetTime)));

    std::cout << "\nAfter sort: ";
    for (auto& v : values)
        std::cout << v << " ";
}
```

Depending on the time of the run it will print something similar to

> Before sort: [2015-Apr-24 11:16:49] [2015-Apr-24 11:16:45] [2015-Apr-24 11:18:05] [2015-Apr-24 11:18:58] [2015-Apr-24 11:17:00] [2015-Apr-24 11:15:09]
>
> After sort: [2015-Apr-24 11:18:58] [2015-Apr-24 11:18:05] [2015-Apr-24 11:17:00] [2015-Apr-24 11:16:49] [2015-Apr-24 11:16:45] [2015-Apr-24 11:15:09]